# Access PlaceHolder from a method

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to do this:

---

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trida_kalendar kal1 = new trida_kalendar();
        kal1.SetID(5);
        Response.Write(kal1.GetID());

        trida_kalendar kal2 = new trida_kalendar();
        stranka.Controls.Add(kal2.getcal());
    }

    private class trida_kalendar {
        private int pint = -1;

        public Calendar getcal() {
            Calendar pokus = new Calendar();
            pokus.ID = "pokus1";
            pokus.Width = 500;
            pokus.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(pokus__SelectionChanged);
            return pokus;
        }

        public void pokus__SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // But this doesnt work :-( 
            // It shows message: Cannot access a non-static member of outer type _Default 
            // via nested _Default.trida_kalendar

            /*
            Calendar kolo = (Calendar)stranka.FindControl("kalendar1");
            string hh = kolo.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            Response.Write("Cosi" + hh);
            */

        }

        public int GetID() {
            return pint;
        }

        public void SetID(int id) {
            pint = id;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <p>pokus</p>

    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="stranka" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

But this doesnt work :-( It shows message:

> Cannot access a non-static member of
>   outer type _Default via nested
>   _Default.trida_kalendar

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Here is it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Kalendar k2 = new Kalendar();
    stranka.Controls.Add(k2.novyKalendar(1));
    k2.vybraniDatumu += new EventHandler(udalost__vybraniDatumu);
}

private void udalost__vybraniDatumu(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar kalendar = (Calendar)stranka.FindControl("kalendar1");
    string cislo = kalendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
    Response.Write("Cosi" + cislo);
}

private class Kalendar {

    public Calendar novyKalendar(int cid) {
        Calendar kalendar = new Calendar();
        kalendar.ID = ("kalendar" + cid);
        kalendar.Width = 500;
        kalendar.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(kalendar__SelectionChanged);
        return kalendar;
    }

    public EventHandler vybraniDatumu;

    private void kalendar__SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (vybraniDatumu != null)
        {
            vybraniDatumu(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Good coding